# SQL compare local (group by) max value to global max value in table

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

can I compare local max value (from `group by`) to global max in one select?
Now if I want to get x which has `group_max_y == global_max_y` value I use this query

```
SELECT x FROM table_name GROUP BY x HAVING MAX(y) = (SELECT MAX(y) FROM table_name); 

x y
1 1
1 3
2 1

2 2
2 0

3 3
```

Expected : x = (1,3)

Is there a simple way to do it without using second select?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: sql-server, oracle, mysql...?

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports window functions, you can do:

```
SELECT x, max_y
FROM (
    SELECT x, MAX(y) max_y, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MAX(y) DESC) rn
    FROM table_name 
    GROUP BY x 
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Some databases have neater solutions available. SQL Server has `TOP (1) WITH TIES`, so you can do:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES x, MAX(y) max_y
FROM table_name
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY max_y DESC
```

Or for databases that support the standard row-limiting clause, such as Oracle:

```
SELECT x, MAX(y) max_y
FROM table_name
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY max_y DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```